# How to print the contents inside a specific div with all the applied css styling using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a main div with a class called **container** that holds the other divs inside it having their respective css stylings such as spaces and positions of elements. I want the contents inside the **container div** to get printed. I am using javascript for that. However when I click the button the contents in preview become completly plain and have no specified styling. I want the contents to be printed exactly the way it is being displayed with all their respective stylling.

below are the codes.

The name of the css file is **doc.css**

**doc.html** this is the container and the divs inside it.

```
 <div class="container" id="content"> 

        <div class="ttle">

            <p></p>

        </div>
        <div class= "body">

             <p></p>
         </div>
          .
          .
          .

</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function printable(paravalue){
    var backup = document.body.innerHTML;
    var divcontent = document.getElementById(paravalue).innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = divcontent;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = backup;
}
```

Please suggest me how I can print the contents exactly the way they are getting displayed with all the css styling of their respective divs.

Comment: I believe `class="container"` is CSS root selector to design full page. As you lost root - you lost all child styles as well. Or your child has own fully isolated styles (not related from root)?

Comment: container is not the root selector but yes, the divs inside have their own specific styling. So their is no way to add them?

Comment: You would have to create the CSS in a way that no element's styling is dependant on the parent's CSS. Which is more of a problem by itself. A solution would be to make all siblings, menu, footer, etc. `display:none;` while printing or adding an `@media print {}` styling block.

Comment: I just tried the @media print { } but the problem is the container has different divs that hold the contents so when i click the button the contents inside the container shows nothing